# What url to post django-registration form to?

Tags: django-registration

I am trying to set up the most trivial example using django-registration. I am using the one-step work flow.

I have a very basic view for registration when I go to /account/register. If I fill username and password fields, and submit the registration form then I end up back on the same registration page! No errors are flagged (but I can make them flag so they seem to be working).

I can see using the admin tools that no user has been registered. I suspect I am posting the form to the wrong url. Here is what I think is the relevant code. Please help!

Textbook url mappings:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$',
        views.RegistrationView.as_view(),
        name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^register/closed/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/registration_closed.html'
        ),
        name='registration_disallowed'),
    url(r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),
]
```

My template:

```
{% block body_block %}
<h1>Register Here</h1>
        <form method="post" action=".">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out everything was ok. I was entering a password judged to be too weak. The error was flagged differently to invalid email address or invalid username and appeared as an extra bullet point on the password requirements (there were four already!) so I didn't spot it.